# How do i make a modal that can be opened with different trigger buttons using JS

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

This is my first time asking a question in here, so I'm sorry if I do this wrong ...
I'm an intern at a web-shop here in Denmark, where I have been appointed to updating their website. Their current website does NOT use bootstrap, so therefore I cannot use bootstrap answers. Likewise am I not familiar with jQuery, so I would prefer if the answer is usable with JavaScript only. :)

My question is, how do I make a modal that can be triggered from a variety of different buttons?

I've figured out how to make a modal that can be opened with one or two trigger buttons - thanks to another thread in here, the script code for that looks like this:

```
<script>
    //Get the modal
    var prismodal = document.getElementById('prisMatchModal');

    //Get the button that opens the modal
    var prisBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("prisMatchBtn")[0];
    var prisBtn2 = document.getElementsByClassName("prisMatchBtn")[1];

    //Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var prisClose = document.getElementsByClassName("prisClose")[0];

    //When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    prisBtn.onclick = function() {
        prismodal.style.display = "block";
    }

    prisBtn2.onclick = function() {
        prismodal.style.display = "block";
    }

    //When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    prisClose.onclick = function() {
        prismodal.style.display = "none";
    }

    //When the user clicks anywhere outside the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == prismodal) {
            prismodal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this works perfectly as I want it to, but how do I rewrite this, so that no matter how many different trigger buttons there are - and which one of these you press, the modal will open?

Comment: Have your buttons have the same `prisBtn` class and the `prisBtn.onclick` should always open it. You don't need additional classes.

Comment: @eeetee I did try that at the beginning, but then it was only the last button that worked as a trigger. All of my buttons, that opens the modal that says something about the price, has the class prisMatchBtn.